# Navigation on destination reached does not reach to its callback

Tags: android, routes, navigation, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am navigating to a huge number of points or route in a map which follows rerouting, but when user reach the destination, it neither reaches the navigation call back method `onDestinationReached` now shows any effect on the map.

Is it the problem of SKobbler map on navigation to the long route? Another problem when the route is as shown in the figure, navigation on simulation stops without user interference.

[image: route]

Answer (score 1):

If you've arrived at the destination (or in its vicinity) then the callback should be triggered.

The only way of knowing what is happening would be to log the actual trip and then replay it to see what the SDK thinks it is happening.

To log the trip you can use the [SKPositionLoggingManager](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/positioner/logging/SKPositionLoggingManager.html) class

```
 private void startNavigation() { 
    //..... navigation settings 
    if (configuration.getNavigationType() == SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.REAL) { 
            navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.REAL); 
            Date date = new Date(); 
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"); 
            final File navigationLogsFolder = 
                    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "YourFileName" 
                            + File.separator); 
            if (!navigationLogsFolder.exists()) { 
                navigationLogsFolder.mkdirs(); 
            } 
            final String fileName = navigationLogsFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + dateFormat.format(date); 

            SKPositionLoggingManager.getInstance().startLoggingPositions(fileName, SKPositionLoggingManager.SPositionLoggingType.SK_POSITION_LOGGING_TYPE_LOG); 
        } 

        navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings); 
      }
```

Note that :

1. In this example, logging device positions is started before the navigation is started.
2. There are options to pause, resume and stop the logging process to current file. Please make sure you also call SKPositionLoggingManager().stopLoggingPositions() when logging should be stopped

After you have the log you can then replay the log using the "[simulate from log](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec021)" navigation option. Looking at the trip vs the real route will point out the problem.